# Локализация названия страницы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки, конкурс

Отсутствует локализация названия страницы при просмотре [конкурсных вопросов определённой метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?tab=Bounties):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А также RSS соответствующей страницы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Притом с локализацией [общего раздела конкурсных вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=bounties) всё в порядке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как и соответствующего RSS:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Bountied

Добавил переводы. Сегодня-завтра с выкаткой новой версии движка появится.